# The integral $\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{x^4e^x}{(e^x-1)^2} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How to calculate the following integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^4e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
I would like to solve this integral by means of two different ways: for example, integration by parts and using Residue Theorem.

Comment: Hint: the exponential term is an exact derivative of another function.  Find that function and integrate by parts.

Answer (score 10):

I will generalise this integral to solve
$$I_n=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^ne^x}{(e^x-1)^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
Applying integration by parts and L'Hôpital's rule gives
$$\begin{align}
I_n
&=\left[-\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}\right]_0^\infty+n\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{e^x-1}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=n\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{e^x-1}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=n\,\zeta(n)\,\Gamma(n)\\
&=\zeta(n)\,\Gamma(n+1)\\
\end{align}$$
where $\Re{(n)}\gt1$. The last equality follows from the famous Bose integral (See proofs at [1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html), [2](http://www.robertobigoni.eu/Matematica/Integrali/IntegraliBose/BoseIntegrals.html) and [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226247/a-integral-involving-riemann-zeta-function-and-gamma-function-int-0-infty)). The answer required is then given by
$$I_4=\zeta(4)\,\Gamma(5)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}\cdot4!=\frac{4\pi^4}{15}$$

Comment: You beat me. Very nice (+1)

Comment: You can also generalise further viz. $e^x-1\mapsto e^x-a$ with polylogarithms.

Comment: $@$J.G. I presume that $a \le 1$?

Comment: @JanG If you want a finite integral, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$ \frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n $$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^4e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}\mathrm{d}x&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{x^4e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-x})^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=&\int_0^\infty x^4e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)e^{-nx}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty(n+1)x^4e^{-(n+1)x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{24}{(n+1)^4}\\
&=&24\zeta(4)\\
&=&\frac{4\pi^4}{15}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: How would be the solution using Residue Theorem? (Complex variables).

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^4e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}\ dx\overset{e^{-x}=y}{=}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{(1-x)^2}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln^4x\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4!}{n^4}=4!\zeta(4)$$

Answer (score 1):

The computation of the given integral becomes in one step (partial integration) $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty\frac {x^4e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}\; dx=-
 \int_0^\infty x^4\left(\frac 1{e^x-1}\right)'\; dx
=\color{blue}{4J_-(4)}$ with the notations 
$$
J_\pm(s) =
\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\cdot\frac 1{e^x\pm1}\; dx
\ ,
$$
and $J_-(4)$ is directly related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Definition.

Instead of using the known special values of the zeta function, here is an explicit calculation using the **Residue Theorem**.

---

Let $f_s$ (with $s=2,4,6,8\dots$ for our Eulerian purposes) be the function
$$
f_s(z)=\frac{z^{s-1}}{e^z-1}\ ,
$$
defined on the complex plane without the obvious poles of the denominator.
(Note that $0$ is a removable singularity in the cases of interest.) The computational idea for $J_+(4)$ comes after the substition $x=2y$ in
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_-(4)
&=2^3
\int_0^\infty y^3\cdot\frac 2{e^{2y}-1}\; dy
\\
&=8
\int_0^\infty y^3\left(\frac 1{e^y-1}-\frac 1{e^y+1}\right)\; dy
\qquad\color{red}{(*)}
\\
&=8J_-(4)-8J_+(4)\ ,
\\[2mm]
&\qquad\qquad\text{ and in this spirit we get}
\\[2mm]
1\cdot J_-(2) &= 2\cdot J_+(2)
\\
7\cdot J_-(4) &= 8\cdot J_+(4)
\\
31\cdot J_-(6) &= 32\cdot J_+(6)
\end{aligned}
$$
and so on.

Fix now some $R>0$, and consider the rectangle contour $C(R)$ with corners, in order, $0,R,R+i\pi,i\pi$:

[image: Computation of zeta values at positive even integers using the Residue Theorem]

The integral of $f_4$ on $C(R)$ vanishes by the Residue Theorem.
We let now $R\to+\infty$.

- The integral of $f_4$ from $0$ to $R$ converges to $J_-(4)$, the integral we need.
- The integral of $f_4$ from $R$ to $R+i\pi $ converges to $0$, because of the exponential term in the denominator.
- The integral of $f_4$ from $R+i\pi$ to $i\pi$ converges to 
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  -\int_0^\infty(x+i\pi)^3\cdot \frac 1{e^{x+i\pi}-1}\; dx
  &=\int_0^\infty(x+i\pi)^3\cdot \frac 1{e^x+1}\; dx
  \\
  &=J_+(4)-3\pi^2\; J_+(2)\text{ modulo }i\Bbb R\ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- The integral of $f_4$ on the segment $[0,i\pi]$ must be computed, for a general even $s>0$ we can work similarly: 
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \int_{i\pi}^0 z^3
  \cdot \frac 1{e^z-1}\; dz
  &=
  -\int_0^\pi i^3t^3\cdot
  \frac1{(\cos t-1)+i\sin t}\; d(it)
  \text{ with }z=it
  \\
  &=
  \int_0^\pi it^3
  \cdot\frac1{2i\sin(t/2)\;(\cos (t/2)+i\sin(t/2))}\; i\; dt
  \\
  &=
  \int_0^\pi it^3\cdot\frac{\cos (t/2)-i\sin(t/2)}{2\sin(t/2)}\; dt
  \\
  &=
  \int_0^\pi \frac 12 t^3\; dt
  \text{ modulo }i\Bbb R\ .
  \\
  \end{aligned}
  $$

---

Using the above method, we reduce the computation of $J\pm(4)$ to the one of $J_\pm(2)$. It may be useful to write explicitly the relation obtained by using the Residue Theorem for some more values. (We need only the relations for $2$ and $4$.)
$$
\begin{aligned}
0 &= J_-(2) + 0 
\underbrace{-\int_0^\infty x\cdot\frac 1{-(e^x+1)}\; dx}
_{=J_+(2) }
-\int_0^\pi\frac 12\cdot t\; dt
\\
0 &= J_-(4) + 0 
\underbrace{-\int_0^\infty \text{Real}((x+i\pi)^3)\cdot\frac 1{-(e^x+1)}\; dx}
_{=J_+(4)-3\pi^2 J_+(2)}
+\int_0^\pi\frac 12\cdot t^3\; dt
\\
0 &= J_-(6) + 0 
\underbrace{-\int_0^\infty \text{Real}((x+i\pi)^5)\cdot\frac 1{-(e^x+1)}\; dx}
_{=J_+(6)-10\pi^2 J_+(4) +5\pi^4J_+(2)}
-\int_0^\pi\frac 12\cdot t^5\; dt
\end{aligned}
$$ 
and so on.

This gives rise to
$$
\begin{aligned}
+\frac 1{2\cdot 2}\pi^2
&=
J_-(2) +[\ J_+(2)\ ]\ ,
\\
-\frac 1{2\cdot 4}\pi^4
&=
J_-(4) +[\ J_+(4)-3\pi^2J_+(2)\ ]\ ,
\\
+\frac 1{2\cdot 6}\pi^6
&=
J_-(6) +[\ J_+(6)-10\pi^2J_+(4)+5\pi^4 J_+(2)\ ]\ ,
\\
-\frac 1{2\cdot 8}\pi^8
&=
J_-(8) +[\ J_+(6)-21\pi^2 J_+(6) + 35\pi^4 J_+(4)-7\pi^6J_+(2)\ ]\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and so on. (In the pattern, the coefficients are binomial coefficients, appearing in the terms of the binomial expansion of $(x+i\pi)$ to the power $1,3,5,7$ and so on.)

---

We are now in position to compute the integral in the OP, and also check:
$$
\zeta(s)=\frac 1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\; dx
=
\frac 1{\Gamma(s)}J_-(s)
$$
for some first eulerian values of $s$ (namely two, four, six, ...)

- The first line above gives $\frac 14\pi^2=\frac{1+2}2J_-(2)$, so $J_-(2) =\frac 16\pi^2$. Because $\Gamma(2)=1!=1$, this gives a proof of $\zeta(2)=\frac 1{1!}J_-(2)=\frac 16\pi^2$.
- The second line gives the value for $J_-(4)+J_+(4)=\frac{7+8}8 J_-(4)$ as $3\pi^2 J_+(2)-\frac 1{2\cdot 4}\pi^4
  =\pi^4\left( 3\cdot\frac 12\cdot \frac 16-\frac 18\right)=\frac 18\pi^4$, so
  $$
  J_-(4)=
  \frac 1{15}\pi^4\ .
  $$
  Because $\Gamma(4)=3!=6$, this gives a proof of $\zeta(4)=\frac 1{3!}J_-(4)=\frac 1{90}\pi^4$.

This also answers the OP, the integral to be comupted is
$$
\color{blue}{
\boxed{\qquad
4J_-(4)=\frac 4{15}\pi^4\ .
\qquad}}
$$

- Let us compute also $J_-(6)$. The third line gives the equality of $J_-(6)+J_+(6)=\frac{31+32}{32}J_-(6)$ and $\left(\frac 1{2\cdot 6}+10\cdot\frac 78\cdot\frac 1{15}-5\cdot\frac 12\cdot\frac 16\right)\pi^6
  =\frac {1+7-5}{12}\pi^6=\frac 14\pi^6$.  This gives $J_-(6)=\frac {32}{63}\cdot\frac 14\pi^6=\frac 8{63}\pi^6$. This is also a check of $\zeta(6)$ being $\frac 1{5!}\cdot
  \frac 8{63}\pi^6=\frac 1{945}\pi^6$.

---

Note: All computations were done explicitly, no details were omitted. This makes the answer long, too long, but the computational idea is already clear from the position $\color{red}{(*)}$, when the contour to be used  is known.