# how Riemann pass from the Euler product to the expression with exponential...

Tags: riemann-zeta

In his famous article Riemann about Zeta hypothesis start from the Euler's product and rewrite it as an integral. Can someone explain me how this passage is done, because, it's evident for the great Riemann but not for me …in other word how Riemann does to pass from the first to the second equation?

Comment: You should write down which formulas you are talking about.

Comment: yes i would but i didn't manage to do it.  i'm not able to use well yet those Tex tools. Maybe i can insert 
https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Sur_le_nombre_de_nombres_premiers_inférieurs_à_une_taille_donnée_(Riemann,_trad._Laugel). It's about the 2 first formula.. how he get it ?

Comment: The two equations aren’t really related. They’re both “elementary” facts. Note that we nowadays call $\Gamma(s)$ the function that Riemann calls $\Pi(s-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4034838) what you are looking for? At the link is a detailed proof following the approach outlined in Riemann's paper.