# Sum of Fermi-Dirac integrals with opposite chemical potentials: closed form (Le Bellac eq. 1.13)

Tags: gamma-function, polylogarithm, polygamma, fermi-dirac-integral

I am trying to reproduce the result of eq. (1.13) in [Le Bellac's Thermal Field Theory book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/thermal-field-theory/327ADC94F9AF342A6355EA65F1E6991A) to compute the grand canonical potential of a gas of massless fermions:

$$ 
Ω = - \frac{V T^4}{6 π^2} \int_0^\infty dk\ k^3 \left[ \frac{1}{e^{\beta(k - \mu)} +1 } + \frac{1}{e^{\beta(k + μ)} + 1} \right] = -\frac{V}{6π^2} \left[ \frac{7 π^4 T^4}{60} + \frac{\mu^2 \pi^2 T^2}{2} + \frac{\mu^4}{4} \right].
$$

I know how to demonstrate that the Fermi-Dirac integral can be expressed in terms of  $\Gamma$ function and polylogarithms if $\mu = 0$, see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226247/a-integral-involving-riemann-zeta-function-and-gamma-function-int-0-infty) for the Einstein-Bose statistics, showing that
$$
\int_0^\infty dx \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x - 1} = \zeta(s) \Gamma(s),
$$

but I am not able to derive a similar relation for the case with $\mu \neq 0$.

Nevertheless this relation exists, see e.g. the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#iii):

$$
F_s = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s+1)} \int_0^\infty dt \frac{t^s}{e^{t-x} +1 } = - Li_{s+1}(-e^x).
$$

Comment: I would try Digital Lib. Math Func. 25.12.13 and 25.11.14, closed form for Bernoulli polynomial, and algebra.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, this is an instance of the reflection formula $$-\operatorname{Li}_n(-e^{a})-(-1)^n\operatorname{Li}_n(-e^{-a})=\frac{(2\pi i)^n}{n!}B_n\left(\frac12+\frac{a}{2\pi i}\right)\qquad(|\Im a|<\pi)$$ mentioned also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), with a [proof sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Series_representations) of a more general result.

Perhaps more elementarily, we get a recurrence for $I_n(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^n f(a,z)\,dz$, where $$f(a,z)=\frac1{e^{z+a}+1}+\frac1{e^{z-a}+1}-\frac2{e^z+1}\qquad(a\in\mathbb{R})$$ (note that $f(a,z)=-f(a,-z)=f(a,z+2\pi i)$, so that $I_n(a)=0$ for even $n$), using $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\big(z^n-(z+2\pi i)^n\big)f(a,z)\,dz=\pi i\left((\pi i)^n-\frac12(\pi i+a)^n-\frac12(\pi i-a)^n\right),$$ which is an application of the residue theorem. *(But not a closed form this way.)*