# Generalize $ \int_0^\infty \frac{t^3 \, dt}{e^t + 1} = \frac{7 \cdot 31}{8} \zeta(4)$ to the number field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Tags: improper-integrals, algebraic-number-theory, laplace-transform

I found in a physics textbook an integral formula, that mentions both an [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) and a zeta function:

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{t^3 \, dt}{e^t + 1} = \frac{7 \cdot 31}{8} \zeta(4) = \frac{7 \, \pi^4}{120} $$

Is it possible to express the [Dedekind zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function) over the number field $K = \mathbb{Q}(i)$ as an integral transform? The ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[i]$:

$$ \zeta_K(4) = \sum_{I \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K} \frac{1}{N_{K/Q}(I)^4} = \sum_{ (a+bi)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i]} \frac{1}{(a^2 + b^2)^2} $$

There is some redundancy as the ideals $(a+bi)$ and $(a-bi)$ are the same, i.e. $(a+bi)\mathbb{Z}[i] = (a-bi)\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

---

This seems to be the Laplace transform or the Mellin transform (e.g. integrate over $(\mathbb{R}^\times, \frac{dx}{x})$.

- [Integral Representation of the Zeta Function: $\zeta(s)=\frac1{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103139/integral-representation-of-the-zeta-function-zetas-frac1-gammas-int-0?rq=1)
- [Prove $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)} dx=7\zeta(4)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3346609/prove-int-0-infty-frac-ln2x-ln1xx1x-dx-7-zeta4)

Indeed there seems to be something mechanical about this entire set of calculations.